# Finding a span tag with a 'variable'? but no class - Beautiful soup/Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup and Python to find a span tag that doesnt seem to have a class.

I am wanting to get the text "*1hr ago*" in the span tag, it has a... Variable? called "*data-automation*" but I can't seem to find out how to find that using beautiful soup.

The first span has a class of "`_3mgsa7- _2CsjSEq _2gpxOIH _15GBVuT _3VdCwhL _2Ryjovs`" which does produce the text using my code but it also has an error.

can anyone help me fix the error or explain how I would find the "data-automation" span tag?

**MY CODE:**

```
joblist =soup.find_all('article', class_='_37iADb_ _3BsYYYt')
for job in joblist:
    listed = job.find('span', class_="_3mgsa7- _2CsjSEq _2gpxOIH _15GBVuT _3VdCwhL _2Ryjovs").text
    print(f'listed {listed}')
```

**ERROR:**

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Scraping1\ScrapeTut 2 - scraping websites.py", line 34, in <module>
        listed = job.find('span', class_="_3mgsa7- _2CsjSEq _2gpxOIH _15GBVuT _3VdCwhL _2Ryjovs").text
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

**WEBSITE HTML CODE:**

```
<span class="_3mgsa7- _2CsjSEq _2gpxOIH _15GBVuT _3VdCwhL _2Ryjovs">
  <span class="">
    <span aria-hidden="true" data-automation="jobListingDate">1h ago</span>
  </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Can you include the url of the website your trying to scrap ?

Comment: try printing type of the `job` and type of the `listed` with `type(job)` and `type(listed)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select a `<span>` element with a specific attribute (such as `data-automation`) by passing an `attrs` dict as a keyword argument to `.find()` or `.find_all()`. See the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments).

To find `<span>`'s where `data-automation` has any value:

```py
soup.find('span', attrs={'data-automation': True})
```

Where `data-automation` has a specific value:

```py
soup.find('span', attrs={'data-automation': 'jobListingDate'})
```